# Wrapping C++ project using cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I would like to wrap a c++ project using cython for using inside a python code. The main class has instances from other local classes. Do I have to write pyx files for every class that has been used or wrapping only the main class is enough?

Thank you in advance!

---

Edit:

Here is the code that I want to wrap:
https://github.com/vojirt/asms/tree/master/src
I would like to wrap colortracker function, as other classes are used in this class, do I need to wrap them as well?

Comment: I think this question needs more detail to be answerable, but: you only need to wrap what you want to use from Python, you don't need to wrap implementation details.

Comment: What if the classes included by the main class are used in the code? for example, if main functions return or get an input of the type of one these other classes.

Comment: Looking at your example you'd probably have to wrap `ColorTracker`, `BBox` and `cv::Mat` if you want to use the functions that need them. You might be able to convert a numpy array to a `cv::Mat` within Cython instead of using a wrapper class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to DavidW, the problem is solved. I used this code for wrapping cv::Mat:

```
cdef extern from "opencv2/core/core.hpp" namespace "cv":
    cdef cppclass Mat:
        Mat() except +
        void create(int, int, int)
        void* data
```

It was only needed to wrap classes and functions directly used in public functions of colortracker class.